# How to pg_dumpall from remote server to local machine and local machine to remote server

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

I need to do the new installation for which i need to copy my database from current installation. i need the pg_dumpall command for remote server to local machine.

I have already tried this but it works only for dump and doesnt work for dumpall

```
pg_dump -h hostname -Fc -o -U username database > databaseall.sql
```

and

```
pg_dumpall -h hostname -p 5432 -U username > databaseall.sql
```

gives error

```
pg_dumpall: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_authid
pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolinherit, rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit, rolpassword, rolvaliduntil, rolreplication, rolbypassrls, pg_catalog.shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') as rolcomment, rolname = current_user AS is_current_user FROM pg_authid ORDER BY 2
```

and

```
pg_dumpall -h hostname -p 5432 -U username -c -o -f "databaseall.sql"
```

gives error

```
pg_dumpall: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_authid
pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT rolname FROM pg_authid ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: You need to run `pg_dumpall` as the superuser, e.g. `pg_dumpall -U postgres ....`

Comment: i ran pg_dumpall as superuser but it dumped all in text format in the terminal but i need it in sql format on local machine. Can u give the full command.

Comment: pg_dumpall creates a SQL script (text format), you need to redirect that to a file using `> alldb.sql` or use `-f ...` as you did

Comment: pg_dumpall -h hostname -p 5432 -U postgres > databaseall5.sql
Password: 
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
$ pg_dumpall -h hostname -p 5432 -U postgres > databaseall5.sql
Password: 
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: postgres@iitians:/home/network$ pg_dumpall -h hostname -p 5432 -U postgres -c -o -f "databaseall7.sql"
Password: 
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: postgres@iitians:/home/network$ pg_dumpall > alldb.sql
bash: alldb.sql: Permission denied

Comment: postgres@iitians:/home/network$ pg_dumpall -c -o -f "databaseall.sql"
pg_dumpall: could not open the output file "databaseall.sql": Permission denied
postgres@iitians:/home/network$ pg_dumpall -c -o -f alldb4.sql
pg_dumpall: could not open the output file "alldb4.sql": Permission denied
postgres@iitians:/home/network$ pg_dumpall -f alldb4.sql
pg_dumpall: could not open the output file "alldb4.sql": Permission denied
postgres@iitians:/home/network$ pg_dumpall > alldb4.sql
bash: alldb4.sql: Permission denied
postgres@iitians:/home/network$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the pg_dumpall/psql commands to dump and restore

```
pg_dumpall > alldb.sql
```

to load in the other intance

```
psql -f alldb.sql postgres
```

Comment: where to add server host. i need to download the database to my local machine from remote server. Then destroy that server and rebuilt that server with same database. Hope u got the query

Comment: postgres@iitians:/home/network$ pg_dumpall > alldb.sql
bash: alldb.sql: Permission denied

Comment: the pg_dumpall/psql commands have options to set host/port/user etc,  in this case  -h is the host -p the port, to know other options write:

     pg_dumpall --help/ psql --help



and you will see all options about this command